# What is the logic behind the word "lithe"?

Tags: meaning, usage

The Free Dictionary defines the word in the question as follows:

> lithe​
> (līth)
>
> adj. lith·er, lith·est
>
> 1. Readily bent; supple: lithe birch branches.
> 2. Marked by effortless grace: a lithe ballet dancer.

I've looked through other dictionaries and some of them say that this word only applies to things that have the ability to flex or bend easily into whatever shape someone wants them to. Others say that lithe has the connotation of "flexible, supple and thin".

After contemplating, I've come to the conclusion that this word has the meanings of "easily flexible" and "a young healthy, perhaps athletic, person characterized with the ability to contort and bend their body with fluid graceful movements". Am I wrong in my assessment?

Comment: Your quotation "a young healthy, perhaps athletic, person with the ability to contort and bend their body with fluid graceful movements" doesn't appear anywhere at https://www.thefreedictionary.com/lithe. Where did you find that meaning?

Comment: https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/lithe and https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/lithe. At least 70 percent of the aforementioned quote's logic for the second definition comes directly from Cambridge Dictionary.

Comment: For example, "(of a body) thin and attractive, and able to move easily and gracefully, or (of movements) easy and graceful:" and "young, healthy, attractive, and able to move and bend smoothly:" Both entries are from Cambridge Dictionary

Comment: So make a long story short, I pretty much used Cambridge's dictionary entries as a template for my interpretation. Somewhere along the way, I must have subconsciously conflated this dictionary's logic with the Free Dictionary's entries' logic.

Comment: Oh, OK, so you wrote that quotation yourself. I asked because it describes a person, whereas "lithe" is never a noun (as OB notes in the answer below).

Comment: It's preferable to talk about a word's meaning, sense or (full) definition rather than its  *logic*.

Comment: Are you the same person who asked [an identical question on ELU?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/590202/what-is-the-true-meaning-behind-lithe-am-i-wrong-in-my-understanding)

Answer (score 6):

Your two definitions are correct and "a young healthy, perhaps athletic, *person*..." might be *described* as lithe. But lithe is an adjective: it doesn't **mean** "a young healthy, perhaps athletic, *person*...".

[Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/lithe) has:

> **lithe**
>
> (especially of a person's body) thin, supple, and graceful.

Comment: @airmonk  I am particularly well acquainted with an exceptionally fit and lithe septuagenarian, who would take it amiss if any such definition were to exclude her.